# Jackson JSON lib how to specify start of the element to deserialize

Tags: jackson

I am using jackson to deserialize a json data. I am using objectmapper to de-serialize the data and want to ignore unknown properties using `mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`

Is there a way in Jackson to specify the start of the element which I want to deserialize? My JSON data has some more elements in it but I am interested only in some element to deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object structure has to match JSON structure, so oftentimes it is most convenient to just use wrapper classes if necessary. Something like:

```
class Response {
  public Thing value;
}
class Thing {
  public String name;
}
```

so even if you just wanted "name", you would do something like:

```
Response resp = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, Response.class);
String name = response.value.name;
```

If so, you can omit defining properties you don't care about; or define them and not use.

Comment: It does not have to match the structure. You can ignore unknown properties that exist in json but not in class : http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html

Answer (score 0):

JAXB supports XPath expressions to map elements to classes through the `@XmlPath(...)`.

Not sure if you can skip the root element, but for nested, you can make  properties inline using `@XmlPath(".")`.

Not sure if Jackson supports that, but [EclipeLink JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) does.